# How can I simplify $\sqrt{3^2 + 3^2\tan^2\theta}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\sqrt{3^2 + 3^2\tan^2\theta}$$

$$ = (3)(3\tan\theta) = 9\tan\theta $$

I've simplified it like this but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Comment: Certainly not correct. Is $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = ab$ in general? No. Ask instead: what is $1 + \tan^2\theta$ equal to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align} \sqrt{3^2 + 3^2\tan^2\theta} &= \sqrt{9(1+\tan^2 \theta)} \\ 
& = \sqrt 9 \cdot \sqrt {1 + \tan^2 \theta} \\ 
& = 3\sqrt{\sec^2\theta} \\
&= 3|\sec \theta| \end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{3^2+3^2\tan^2 x}$$
$$3 \sqrt{1+\tan ^2x}=3\sqrt{\sec^2 x}=3|\sec x|$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$5x+5y=5(x+y) \text{ distributive property}$$
$$\sqrt{9\cdot 16} = \sqrt{9}\cdot\sqrt{16}\text{ root of a product property}$$

$$\begin{align}
opposite^2 + adjacent^2 &= hypotenuse^2\\
\frac{opposite^2 + adjacent^2}{adjacent^2}&=\frac{hypotenuse^2}{adjacent^2}\\
\bigg(\frac{opposite}{adjacent}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\frac{adjacent}{adjacent}\bigg)^2&=\bigg(\frac{hypotenuse}{adjacent}\bigg)^2\\
\tan^2 x + 1 &= \sec^2 x
\end{align}$$

Answer (score -4):

You have

$$\sqrt{9(1-tan^2(x)} = \sqrt{9 \sec^2(x)} = 3\sec(x).$$

Comment: It should be 1+tan^2(theta). Also, sqrt(sec^2(theta))=|sec(theta)|, rather than just sec(theta).